# Best way to check if a shell command has executed successfully

Tags: python, bash

```
import os

val = os.popen("ls | grep a").read()
```

Let's say I want to check if a given directory has a any file named `a`. If the directory doesn't have a file with `a` in it the `val` is empty and if not `val` should be assigned with some output gotten from executing that command.

**Are there any cases where the value of `val` could be still something even with empty output?** In this case, there are no files with `a` but could `val` still have some value? Are there any cases where the output looks empty when we execute on a terminal, but `value` still has some value (e.g. white space)?

**Is it an effective approach to use *in general*?** (I am not really trying to check for files with certain names. This is actually just an example.)

Are there any better ways of doing such a thing?

Comment: I don't have time to write a comprehensive answer. Short answer: (1) Checking output is okay, you won't get random whitespace. (2) Checking exit code is better. Almost all commands report success or failure via exit code. (3) Avoid calling out to the shell; it's a heavyweight tool and makes your code less portable. There are usually native Python alternatives. In this example, I would use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html) library.

Comment: Checking exit code is okay, but the only problem with that is it prints the output as well which is something I don't want at some times.

Comment: Use `grep -q` to suppress its output. Many commands have such an option. For ones that don't use `>/dev/null` to suppress stdout or `>/dev/null 2>&1` to suppress both stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `python3` subprocess, where you can use the `check` parameter. Then your command will throw an error if it does not succeed:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.run(["ls | grep a"], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# proc = subprocess.run(["ls | grep a"], shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True) # starting python3.7
print(proc.stdout)
```

but as @JohnKugelman suggested, in this case you'd better use `glob`:

```
import glob
files_with_a = glob.glob("*a*")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reallly go for the approach of running a os command from python, I'd recommend using the `subprocess` package:

```
import subprocess
command = "ls | grep a"
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print(process.returncode)
```